# Maximum weight in a block?

Tags: weight

How do I find the maximum weight available to extrinsics in a block for a substrate-, FRAME-based chain such as Polkadot?

- I know that there is [`WEIGHT_PER_SECOND`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6ab64863c6e653da5cc468257650a970dbc8e9a1/frame/support/src/weights.rs#L158) value, but it doesn't answer my question since I don't know how many seconds are allowed within a block?
- I tried googling and got [this](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/substrate-weight-and-fees/) article which mentions `MaximumBlockWeight` but that seems to be removed in previous versions of Substrate.

Please help me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The various weight configurations on a Substrate chain are all collected in a `blockWeights` configuration constant which can be found in the System Pallet.

[image]

You can see in the image above the Kusama network has a `maxBlock` configured to `2_000_000_000_000` which is equivalent to "2 seconds of weight".

This is generated via a builder pattern defined here:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/system/src/limits.rs

In the Substrate node, you can find the builder definition inside the Runtime configuration:

```
pub RuntimeBlockWeights: BlockWeights = BlockWeights::builder()
    .base_block(BlockExecutionWeight::get())
    .for_class(DispatchClass::all(), |weights| {
        weights.base_extrinsic = ExtrinsicBaseWeight::get();
    })
    .for_class(DispatchClass::Normal, |weights| {
        weights.max_total = Some(NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO * MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT);
    })
    .for_class(DispatchClass::Operational, |weights| {
        weights.max_total = Some(MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT);
        // Operational transactions have some extra reserved space, so that they
        // are included even if block reached `MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT`.
        weights.reserved = Some(
            MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT - NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO * MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT
        );
    })
    .avg_block_initialization(AVERAGE_ON_INITIALIZE_RATIO)
    .build_or_panic();
```

Obviously a lot of assumptions happening here in the background to calculate all these different weight values, but this is the source of that logic.

Answer (score 8):

How many seconds are available per block comes down to computation power aka the underlying hardware that is supporting the blockchain.

So you are right:

```
pub const WEIGHT_PER_SECOND: Weight = 1_000_000_000_000;
```

> Substrate defines **one unit** of weight as one picosecond of execution time, that is **10^12 weight = 1 second**, or 1,000 weight = 1 nanosecond, on fixed reference hardware (Intel Core i7-7700K CPU with 64GB of RAM and an NVMe SSD).

So a recap:

- 1 unit of weight = 1/1_000_000_000_000 of a second of execution time
- 1_000_000_000_000 units of weight = 1 second
- 1_000 units of weight = 1 nanosecond

**Maximum Block Weight**

> The **maximum block weight** should be equivalent to one-third of the target block time, allocating one third for block construction, one third for network propagation, and one third for import and verification.

So if the block time is 6 seconds then 1/3 would be 2 seconds of weight, which as Shawn mentioned is 2_000_000_000_000 units of weight.

**Maximum weight can be tuned.**

> In order to tune a runtime for different validator hardware assumptions, you can set a different maximum block weight.

> These tuning options give runtime developers a way to make the optimal transaction per second vs. hardware requirement trade-offs for their use case. These trade-offs can be tuned with runtime updates to keep up with hardware and software improvements.

Reference: https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/weight